# How do I limit the longitude extent in Cartopy's LambertConformal and keep the conic looks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

I would like to produce a Lambert Conic plot focused on Europe. I can do the following:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=20.0, central_latitude=45.0, cutoff=30)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=proj)
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However this extends too much to the east and west. I would like to narrow it down to, say, between 10W and 40E. If I add a line `ax.set_extent([-10,40,30,90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())`, I lose the conic "look" of the plot above:

[image]

How can I properly decrease the longitudinal range in Cartopy's LambertConformal, and still maintain the conic looks? Can I give longitude margins and have the first figure adjusted between two meridians, and not have it put in this rectangle? I imagine a triangular shape between two meridians, and an arch at the lower latitude limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=20.0, central_latitude=45.0))
ax.gridlines()
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')

# Lon and Lat Boundaries
xlim = [-10, 40]
ylim = [30, 90]
lower_space = 10 # this needs to be manually increased if the lower arched is cut off by changing lon and lat lims

rect = mpath.Path([[xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                   [xlim[1], ylim[0]],
                   [xlim[1], ylim[1]],
                   [xlim[0], ylim[1]],
                   [xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                   ]).interpolated(20)

proj_to_data = ccrs.PlateCarree()._as_mpl_transform(ax) - ax.transData
rect_in_target = proj_to_data.transform_path(rect)

ax.set_boundary(rect_in_target)
ax.set_extent([xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0] - lower_space, ylim[1]])
```

Adapted from [this example](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/697#issuecomment-157025400).

Output:

[image: Lambert Conic plot focused on Europe]

Comment: This is great! However it is sensitive to the parameters. For example, if I widen the longitude range a bit to `xlim = [-20, 60]` the lower arch is gone. Is there a way to fix that? A universal solution would be great. I don't fully understand how to control the `cutoff` parameter from `LambertConformal` and the `set_extent` together.

Comment: You can fix it as such: `ax.set_extent([xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0] - 20, ylim[1]])`. Not sure about a universal solution - as you can see in the related example, this is more of a hack.