# Fail to add gridlines in cartopy custom shape boundary and stereographic projection

Tags: python, cartopy, gridlines

I am drawing custom shape boundary map which focuses on the Pacific Sector of Southern Ocean (160E~180~60W,-60S~-90S). When adding gridlines, the region (180~60W) lacks gridlines.

[image: Example output showing the problem]

I have tried many solutions (mostly for rectangular projection), but failed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
proj = ccrs.Stereographic(central_longitude=228, central_latitude=-70)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1],projection=proj)
latmin = -90
latmax = -60
lonmin = 150
lonmax = 305
lats = np.linspace(latmax, latmin, latmax - latmin + 1)
lons = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, lonmax - lonmin + 1)
vertices = [(lon, latmin) for lon in range(lonmin, lonmax + 1, 1)] + \
    [(lon, latmax) for lon in range(lonmax, lonmin - 1, -1)]
boundary = mpath.Path(vertices)
ax.set_boundary(boundary, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([170, 320, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1, edgecolor='k')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Gridlines` plotting is problematic in this particular case. The plot involves special boundary, the parallels crossing the international dateline -- these may be the causes of the problem. I hope the answer by @Rutger_Kassies is what you need. However, if you still need the original plot extent, here is another approach.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

proj = ccrs.Stereographic(central_longitude=228, central_latitude=-70)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10/2, 10/2))
ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1], projection=proj)

latmin = -90
latmax = -60
lonmin = 150
lonmax = 305
lats = np.linspace(latmax, latmin, latmax - latmin + 1)
lons = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, lonmax - lonmin + 1)
vertices = [(lon, latmin) for lon in range(lonmin, lonmax + 1, 1)] + \
    [(lon, latmax) for lon in range(lonmax, lonmin - 1, -1)]

boundary = mpath.Path(vertices)
ax.set_boundary(boundary, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([170, 320, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1, edgecolor='k')
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=1, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.3)

# Build gridlines in 2 steps
# First set of gridlines: meridians only
# proper `xlim` is needed to get all the x-labels' visibility set correctly
gl1 = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
            xlocs=range(-180, 359, 20), \
            ylocs=[], \
            xlim=[-2847619, 3537282])  # get these from ax.get_xbound() of previous run

# Second set of gridlines: parallels of latitude only. 
# The lines are terminated at the meridian of the dateline!
gl2 = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
            y_inline=True, \
            ylocs=range(-80, -50, 10), \
            xlocs=[])

# Draw the missing parts of the parallel lines at 70, 80 deg_S
# Colors are set to `red` and `green` intentionally
lons = range(-180, -50, 5)
ax.plot(lons, -80*np.ones(len(lons)), transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), lw=0.5, color="red", zorder=30)
ax.plot(lons, -70*np.ones(len(lons)), transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), lw=0.5, color="green", zorder=30)

# Print the bounds of the plot
print("Bounds:", ax.get_xbound(), ax.get_ybound())
plt.show()
```

[image: spole]

Comment: Also check this link: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/697#issuecomment-157025400 look at pelson's comment for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65690841/4265407 described another method of boundary projection which allows grid to plot correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.Stereographic(central_longitude=228, central_latitude=-70)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1],projection=proj)

ylim = [-90,-60]
xlim = [150,305]

rect = mpath.Path([[xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                   [xlim[1], ylim[0]],
                   [xlim[1], ylim[1]],
                   [xlim[0], ylim[1]],
                   [xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                   ]).interpolated(40)

proj_to_data   = ccrs.PlateCarree()._as_mpl_transform(ax) - ax.transData
rect_in_target = proj_to_data.transform_path(rect)
ax.set_boundary(rect_in_target)

ax.set_extent([150,305,-90,-58], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1, edgecolor='k')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False,
             xlocs=range(-180, 180, 10))
plt.show()
```

[image: map plotting result]